# Wouldn't a plumber, as a subtrade, have to draw up a plan to show the builder in order to explain his pricing? And send a copy to the township?

Tags: plumbing

We want to see the original plan the plumber made for the builder we hired. That way we can see if the plumber did the job the way he priced it and if he decided to cut corners unbeknownst to the builder and violated the contract. Because the plumber put in a bleeder valve, left it open, did not tell us about the valve--we never heard of one before, the builder told us to open the supply valve to use our garden hose, and 22 hours later our basement was flooded out. The supply valve with a bleeder port was in the upstairs bathroom to feed the frost-free valve in the garage below. Isn't the plumber, like an HVAC installer required to submit a plan to the township for approval? If there's no plan required, then how can we hold the plumber accountable for what he has done? And if in the original plan it showed that the supply valve and the feed to the garage hose bib was run on the first floor and done in copper, then we can demand it be done that way and not with plastic pipe from the upstairs bathroom to the hose bib. However, we got a copy of the inspection date for the plumbing and the inspection was done before the plumber put in the line from the bathroom to the garage hose bib. How do we know? Because the date that the vanity arrived from the supplier is after the inspection date. You can't do any plumbing under the sink until the vanity is installed. The inspector didn't do his job and therefore he is at fault for not inspecting and being able to see that a bleeder valve is not needed when a frost-free valve is used. Try getting money out of a township? They just laugh at you and ignore you. At least our township does.

Comment: You've also learned a valuable lesson.  When you turn a valve, you should only hear water running if it was the last closed valve on the line.  A thorough check for leaks is advisable when opening valves for the first time.

Answer (score 4):

I can see your frustration in chasing after a builder and the subcontractor. Unfortunately, I don't think either one is required to submit a detailed plan to the building department of your township.

In general, the builder is required to submit the construction document (building plans, structural calculations) to the jurisdiction for approval, which will be granted if the plan meets the governing building code. The subcontractor, on the other hand, usually is required to bid the work using the builder-supplied bid document or do his/her own calculation based on the requirement indicated on the construction plans. The bid document includes a list of specified material, the cost of material if furnished by him/her, labor, and a work schedule. If the subcontractor decides to use an item that is different from the bid, prior to work, he needs to submit a change order to obtain approval from the builder. Upon granting the work, the subcontractor is required to adhere to the governing code of his/her trade, to maintain good standing on his/her professional and business license and insurance.

If you are interested in tracking down the matter yourself, in this case, you shall first find out who specified this type of valve, and second, whether this type of valve meets the criteria of the plumbing code. And the last, whether the bleeding port shall remain in shutoff position or leave it on. But I highly anticipate it is rather a common fitting wildly used in the trade, that is not addressed by the code, nor it would be critical enough to be noticed by anybody. It is arguable though, that shall the bleeder be kept on or off.

The recourse you have for the incident is your home owner's insurance. Talk to your agent, and let him/her chase it down, and determine the responsible party. Good luck.

Comment: r13: Thank you for your informed and knowlegable answer. I think that will help a lot.